# How do I implement a mod_python style authenhandler/authzhandler using mod_wsgi?

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, mod-python

I have a simple `mod_python` script that provides authentication and authorization for a large static website.  We're migrating from CentOS 4 to Scientific Linux 6 and I discover that `mod_python` isn't bundled anymore so I need to convert to `mod_wsgi`.  All the examples for `mod_wsgi` I've found assume either Basic or Digest authentication which isn't the case for me.

Based on [this](http://plonexp.leocorn.com/xp/leocornus.django.ploneproxy/xps8), it appears I can't readily convert over.

Any pointers?  I'm willing to entertain alternative solutions (well, with the possible exception to using `mod_perl`  =P ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested at:

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_thread/thread/1edd0398206c89a9

to use mod_auth_tkt instead.

http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/